# Display header based on user role and page (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, header

I have created multiple different headers as templates with Elementor.

I would like to display all of the different headers based on user role (Logged in/Logged out) and page.

I'm looking for a code snippet that I could easily customize to assign all of the different headers for different scenarios.

Could someone please create an example code snippet that would:

- Display header **A** for **Logged Out** users on the **entire
  website**, **EXCEPT pages X and Y**.
- Display header **B** for **Logged In** users on the **entire
  website**, **EXCEPT pages X and Y**.
- Display header **C** for **Logged Out** users only on **pages X and
  Y**.
- Display header **D** for **Logged In** users only on **pages X and
  Y**.

This way, people can easily copy the code and customize it to fit their needs.

---

**EDIT**

There's 2 places where I can create templates.

1st one is added by Elementor and is found in **Admin > Templates > Saved Templates**. Here I can create either section or page templates ([Screenshot](https://ibb.co/h1yrhwN)).

2nd one is added by my theme, OceanWP, and is found in **Admin > Theme Panel > My Library**. Here I can create only 1 type of template. The templates created here can later be assigned as custom headers or footers to individual pages or the entire website.

Are the templates created in these 2 places considered to be template parts? Is there a difference where I choose to create the header templates?

Here's a list of the header templates I have created:

|  | Template title | Post ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **A** | Main Header (Logged Out) | 5448 |
| **B** | Main Header (Logged In) | 6714 |
| **C** | Checkout Header (Logged Out) | 6724 |
| **D** | Checkout Header (Logged In) | 3960 |

Here's the page I want to have a different header than the entire website:

|  | Page title | Post ID | Slug |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **X** | Checkout | 18 | checkout |

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
<?php

if (! is_user_logged_in() && ! is_page(array( 'page-x-slug', 'page-y-slug' ))){
  // display header A
}

if (is_user_logged_in() && ! is_page(array( 'page-x-slug', 'page-y-slug' ))){
  // display header B
}

if (! is_user_logged_in() && is_page(array( 'page-x-slug', 'page-y-slug' ))){
  // display header C
}

if (is_user_logged_in() && is_page(array( 'page-x-slug', 'page-y-slug' ))){
  // display header D
}

?>
```

Comment: You should probably use `elseif ` statements instead of multiple `if `.

Comment: @amarinediary Absolutely, you're right. If all scenarios happen at once, then it can be simplified, as you've shown. But they might be separate, too.

Answer (score 1):

The following offer the same result as the previous answer but is minified and has less repetitiveness.

```
<?php
if ( is_page( [ 'page-x', 'page-y' ] ) )
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) 
        get_header( 'B' ); //... header-B.php
    else 
        get_header( 'A' ); //... header-A.php
else
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) 
        get_header( 'D' ); //... header-D.php
    else 
        get_header( 'C' ); //... header-C.php
?>
```

---

### Following your comments

I'm guessing that what you refer as...

> section templates

...are in fact templates part. Instead of using `get_header( string $name );` you would then use `get_template_part( string $slug, string $name = null );`.

`$slug` and `$name` can be anything that you chose.

- Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/

For example, `section-A.php` would be `get_template_part( 'section', 'A' );`.

```
<?php
//...
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) 
        get_template_part( 'section', 'B' ); //... section-B.php
    else 
        get_template_part( 'section', 'A' ); //... section-A.php
?>
```

---

In regards to specifying pages and templates. `is_page()` can take IDs, slugs or titles.

> is_page( int|string|int[]|string[] $page = '' )

| Parameter | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `$page` | `(int|string|int[]|string[])` (Optional) Page ID, title, slug, or array of such to check against. Default value: '' |

- Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/

But you could also use other `is_` function like `is_search()` or `is_archives()`, `is_404()`... etc.

Here is a complete list @ https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

If you want to add multiple conditional statement you can just add `elseif` statements in-between.

```
<?php
if ( is_page( [ 'page-x', 'page-y' ] ) )
    //...

elseif ( is_search() || is_archive() )
    //...

else
    //...
?>
```

If you want to get a better understanding of PHP operators, which are how conditional statements are built, take a look @ https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp

Comment: Hi @amarinediary, thank you for your answer. How do I specify the pages and templates in the code? Do I use post ID's? Also, the templates I have created are considered to be "section templates" not "header templates" as I do not have Elementor Pro. Will this still work?

Comment: Anser was edited @JOKKER; Don't hesitate if you have more question I will update the answer as we go on.

Comment: Hey @amarinediary, I've edited my original question to include more specific information. Could you please use that information to create the code snippet? I do not understand the `section-A.php` part. Where do I find this `... .php` in my templates?

Comment: Your themes behaviour is dictated by those plugins which is why it's such a nightmare. I'm afraid that you don't have at least some knowledge on Wordpress theme architecture we wont go anywhere. What I've written is some pretty basic stuff and can be applied to any theme. I don't know those plugins, and I stay away from visual editor so I don't know how your theme is reacting.

Comment: If once you created the template you can see them in your theme root file then what i've described in my answer can be easily applied. If you can find the slug and name used to create your templates then I would be happy to update my answer, but without any further info I won't be abble to help. Templates are file with the following structure `slug-name.php`.