# Display a different header for authorized and unauthorized users (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Have a nice day

I created a header in the Riode Theme Template and want to make the header display different widgets for authorized and unauthorized users, can anyone-help in this matter?

Tried to implement the code from [(this article)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66624401/display-header-based-on-user-role-and-page-wordpress). Without success, gives an error.

To fully understand the problem, I attach screenshots of the header layout:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ry5SP.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5Pzg.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this ?

```
<?php
if( !function_exists( 'my_is_user_authorized' ) ) {
    // Put here your authorizing logic, for example:
    function my_is_user_authorized() {
        return is_user_logged_in() && current_user_can( 'edit_posts' );
    }
}
?>

<?php if( my_is_user_authorized() ): ?> 

    <!-- HTML For Authorized user -->

    <h1>You Are Authorized</h1>

<?php else: ?>

    <!-- HTML For Unauthorized user -->

    <h1>You Are Not Authorized</h1>

<?php endif; ?>
```